# Adjust values in a time series data set by dragging points on a graph of the data

Tags: r

I know that R has numerous packages, apps, and gadgets that allow a user to create interactive graphs with many data types. However, when it comes to simple time series data or forecast output for a model, are there any interactive abilities to physically change the data by adjusting a line/point graph with the mouse?

I understand this is not useful for most applications.

I'm an operational meteorologist and one useful application of this would be adjusting model output hourly forecasts. Adjusting the numerical output in a spreadsheet can become laborious quickly, especially with many days to adjust so this would speed up that process.

Thanks.